# How to view Hourly based Booking availabitlity of facilities

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I have a Facility table which have the list of all the Facilities. Then I have a Bookings table in which each Booking transaction is added.

### Facility table

```
+-------------+------------+
| Locationkey | FacilityID |
+-------------+------------+
|     1       |   Neptune  |
|     2       |   Jupiter  |
|     3       |   Pluto    |
+-------------+------------+
```

### Booking table

```
+------------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| BookingKey | LocationKey |         StartTime         |          EndTime          |
+------------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|     1      |      1      | '2014-06-11 09:00:00.000' | '2014-06-11 17:00:00.000' |
|     2      |      2      | '2014-06-11 09:00:00.000' | '2014-06-11 12:00:00.000' |
|     3      |      2      | '2014-06-11 13:00:00.000' | '2014-06-11 17:00:00.000' |
|     4      |      3      | '2014-06-11 09:00:00.000' | '2014-06-11 10:00:00.000' |
|     5      |      3      | '2014-06-11 16:00:00.000' | '2014-06-11 17:00:00.000' |
+------------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Now I need to view the hourly availability of the facilities in a list based on the Bookings table for any given date. Availability is shown in HTML and I need to craft the SQL query to pass data to Javascript that generates the HTML.

[image: Facility List with hourly availability]

As long as I get the correct SQL query, then I can worry about the Javascript part. So, I'm not worried about the Javascript and HTML part for now.

Expected result is as follows:

```
+------------+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| FacilityID | 0h | ... | 8h | 9h | 10h | 11h | 12h | 13h | 14h | 15h | 16h | 17h | ... | 23h |
+------------+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Neptune    | 0  | ... | 0  | 1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  | ... |  0  |
| Jupiter    | 0  | ... | 0  | 1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  | ... |  0  |
| Pluto      | 0  | ... | 0  | 1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  | ... |  0  |
+------------+----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Can you explained little bit more what you wanna do exactly

Comment: whats your server side language?

Comment: Hi PEO, i want to get a summery view of bookings by hourly. for example, if i have booking for room1 from 11am-2pm, in those hourly views(for hours 11,12,01) it should show facility not avaibale(i'm showing '1' as for it now)

Comment: Hi  Marcelo Bezerra,
i'm using MS SQL for this

Answer (score 0):

won't you also need the date(s)?

```
| FACILITYID |         DT | H0 | H1 | H2 | H3 | H4 | H5 | H6 | H7 | H8 | H9 | H10 | H11 | H12 | H13 | H14 | H15 | H16 | H17 | H18 | H19 | H20 | H21 | H22 | H23 |
|------------|------------|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|    Jupiter | 2014-06-11 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|    Neptune | 2014-06-11 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|      Pluto | 2014-06-11 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
```

below is an approach, and I stress AN (there are others). I have used a recursive CTE, it could be replaced with a table or a simple non-recursive CTE. I have also cross joined to a single date, I suspect you will need to replace that with a range of dates to suit your situation.

```
;with Hrs (StartAt, StopAt)
as (
    select 0 as StartAt, 1 as StopAt
    union all
    select StartAt + 1 , StopAt + 1
    from Hrs
    where StartAt < 23
    )
select
        FacilityID
      , d.dt
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 0  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h0
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 1  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h1
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 2  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h2
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 3  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h3
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 4  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h4
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 5  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h5
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 6  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h6
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 7  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h7
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 8  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h8
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 9  and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h9
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 10 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h10
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 11 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h11
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 12 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h12
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 13 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h13
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 14 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h14
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 15 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h15
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 16 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h16
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 17 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h17
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 18 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h18
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 19 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h19
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 20 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h20
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 21 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h21
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 22 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h22
      , MAX(case when hrs.StartAt = 23 and Booking.BookingKey IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as h23
from Hrs
cross join (
            select cast('20140611' as date) dt 
           ) as d
cross join Facility
left join Booking on Facility.LocationKey = Booking.LocationKey
                 and cast(booking.StartTime as date) = d.dt
                 and Hrs.StartAt >= datepart(hour,StartTime)
                 and Hrs.StopAt <= datepart(hour,EndTime)
group by
        FacilityID
      , d.dt
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5bfea/2

Answer (score 0):

What exactly works for what you need is depending upon scheduling criteria. I'm making the assumption that the facility is booked in half hour increments since that is what is shown in the screenshot.

Each hour block can contain 1 of 4 values:
0 - Free
1 - Beginning half hour is booked.
0.5 - Trailing half hour is booked.
1.5 - Entire hour is booked.

```
SELECT FacilityID
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 00:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 00:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H0
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 01:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 01:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H1
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 02:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 02:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H2
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 03:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 03:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H3
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 04:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 04:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H4
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 05:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 05:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H5
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 06:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 06:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H6
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 07:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 07:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H7
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 08:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 08:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H8
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 09:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 09:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H9
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 10:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 10:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H10
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 11:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 11:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H11
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 12:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 12:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H12
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 13:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 13:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H13
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 14:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 14:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H14
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 15:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 15:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H15
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 16:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 16:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H16
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 17:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 17:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H17
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 18:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 18:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H18
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 19:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 19:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H19
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 20:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 20:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H20
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 21:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 21:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H21
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 22:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 22:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H22
, SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 23:15:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN '2014-06-11 23:45:00' BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS H23
FROM Booking
LEFT JOIN Facility
ON Booking.LocationKey = Facility.LocationKey
WHERE
  (StartTime >= '2014-06-11 00:00:00' AND
  StartTime < '2014-06-12 00:00:00')
  OR
  (EndTime >= '2014-06-11 00:00:00' AND
  EndTime < '2014-06-12 00:00:00')
 Group By FacilityID;
```